# IE10 hover pseudo class doesn't work without background color

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, hover

I have a div `position:absolute` over a canvas tag. The div uses the hover pseudo class to set `overflow:visible` to create a simple popup-type effect. In Chrome, this works fine. In IE10, the hover pseudo class is only activated when I'm hovering over an element within the div or if I give the div a `background-color`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: show the full css class and html element you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like this can be fixed by using a transparent png as a background image.

EDIT: sorry, shouldve expanded on this more. in ie, if you use the pseudo class of `:hover` on an element that has a transparent background color, the hover is only triggered when the mouse is over a solid/nontransparent spot. this is usually not an issue unless you are doing something like this:

```
<style>
#content {
  height:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
}
#content:hover {
  height:100px;
  overflow:visible;
}
#hoverContent {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
}
</style>
<div id="content">
    <div style="float:left;">wtf</div>
    <div style="float:right;">hrm</div>
    <div id="hoverContent">lol</div>
</div>
```

in ie, if you hover over `#content`, only when the mouse is over 'wtf' or 'hrm' will the overflow content be visible. if you hover BETWEEN the words 'wtf' and 'hrm', youd expect that the hover styles would be applied too because that is part of `#content` but youd be wrong.

to fix this you can either apply a background color or image to `#content`.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a little bit?  It's good to know that you've solved your problem, but as this should be helpful for the next user with your problem it would be helpful to add additional details to make it easier to understand/implement.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use a transparent background color rather than an image:

`background:rgba(0,0,0,0);`

IE10 treats rgba() as a solid color.

Comment: How exactly is this a better solution than a transparent PNG?  Older browsers that don't support `rgba()` (like IE8 and earlier) will display this as opaque.  A transparent PNG should work in all cases.

Comment: Because not all websites need to support IE8 and a transparent png uses more server resources when you send an extra request to fetch it.

Comment: I doubt many people developing for desktop browsers will find themselves in a situation where the performance increase gained by eliminating a single <1kb GET request is more important than breaking the site for more than 10% of the browser market share.  I dream of the day when I have to stop worrying about graceful degradation.

Answer (score 1):

Also one possibility is use of inline svg as the background img. You need only svg element with background 1x1 - no color.

- Pros - No need of additional request
- Cons - IE8 does not support svg

  ```
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22+width%3D%221%22+height%3D%221%22+viewBox%3D%220+0+1+1%22%3E%3Ctitle%3Etransparent+bcg%3C%2Ftitle%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  ```

Sample is already encoded svg to work in all browsers